# Refactor browse file methods to one method

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have several browse methods for parameters which only differ in which setting and which textbox is used. Can I create a lambda or generic method or something to have only one implementation in C#?

```
private void buttonBrowseSrcXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    try
    {
        fileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Settings.Default.XML_Original_File);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException) { }

    if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Settings.Default.XML_Original_File = fileDialog.FileName;
        Settings.Default.Save();
        textBoxSrcXML.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can move this code into a common method and then pass the setting and textbox to this method and call in each of your methods like the one below.

```
BrowseFile("XML_Original_File", textBoxSrcXML);
```

you will need to use these values accordingly in this method.

the method's signature should be something like `private void BrowseFile(string settingName, TextBox textbox)`

Answer (score 0):

The trick was the [] for settings indexing

```
    private void BrowseForStringSettingsFile(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox, string settingKey) {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        try {
            fileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName((string) Settings.Default[settingKey]);
        } catch (ArgumentException) { }

        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            Settings.Default[settingKey] = fileDialog.FileName;
            Settings.Default.Save();
            textBox.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }
```